# Ovi Maps in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

Yahoo stopped their *Yahoo! maps web services* ([link1 :](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/) *We are shutting down this service on September 13, 2011. We suggest using maps from our partner Nokia. Please visit the Ovi Maps API for more information*). How can I use Ovi map as a layer of my OpenLayers map? 
I came through this page where it seems they've managed to use OpenLayers with Ovi : [link 2](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/crschmidt/ovi-mobile/examples/ovi-jq.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ovi Layer at http://svn.openlayers.org/sandbox/crschmidt/ovi-mobile/lib/OpenLayers/Layer/Ovi.js appears to still work: http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/crschmidt/ovi-mobile/examples/ovi.html . (I wrote this in an evening more than a year ago.) However, it's worth noting that the tiles in use there are behind the current version of the Ovi Maps tiles, which probably means that it's using an older version of the API.

Additionally, although I may have written the code, Nokia has absolutely not offered any indication that such a layer is not in violation of their terms of use. Although I don't see any evidence through their terms that such a layer would be in violation, I highly recommend you do a review of the license, and perhaps contact the people running the API to ask for more information in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of that example it seems like an XYZ-layer should do the trick. I think a simple copy-paste from http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/crschmidt/ovi-mobile/examples/ovi-base.js should do the trick.

Comment: Note that using an XYZ layer directly is likely a violation of the Nokia Maps Terms of Service, just like almost all commercial web map providers. The ovi-base.js was a proof of concept, but is not a supported or encouraged way of doing things.